# is alloc not available for my object?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a few custom objects, where one holds a container of the other.

The interface for `ClassObject` has a publicly declared init function like this:

```
@interface ClassObject : NSObject

@property NSDate *earliestDate;
@property NSDate *latestDate;

- (id) initWithHKQuantitySample: (HKQuantitySample *)sample;

@end
```

So I'd like to do the following:

```
ClassObject * newObject = [[ClassObject alloc] initWithClass2Object:sample];
```

However, I am being stopped because Xcode is not recognizing `alloc` as a valid selector and is only suggested `alloca(size_t)`, which is most definitely not what I want.

What am I doing wrong?

This seems like such a basic thing, I can't figure out what I am missing or have forgotten.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: have you done a thing like e.g. `#import "ClassObject.h"`...?

Comment: I can't tell from your code whether you meant `initWithClass2Object` or `initWithHKQuantitySample`, but it's a bit confusing. At the very least you should clean this up in your question so it's easier for others to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't imported the header file for your custom class, it won't be recognized by Xcode. Wherever you want to use `ClassObject`, you should make sure you have this:

```
#import "ClassObject.h"
```

Other than that, your class looks fine to me.